# Why is Main.cpl called Main?

Tags: windows, control-panel

Type `main` into PowerShell, and it opens the mouse settings from Control Panel. This is because:

```
> gcm main

CommandType     Name         Version    Source
-----------     ----         -------    ------
Application     main.cpl     10.0.1904… C:\Windows\system32\main.cpl
```

[There exists a Microsoft Support page on the various CPL files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-control-panel-cpl-files-4dc809cd-5063-6c6d-3bee-d3f18b2e0176), but no explanation is given as to where the names individually come from. Most of them make sense though, except for Main.cpl.

Why is Main.cpl called Main?

Answer (score 2):

Main.cpl originally handled the settings for more than just the mouse, and I would guess it was called "main" because of this. Going back to the Windows 95 days it handled the following (and possibly other features I can't remember):

```
control main.cpl          - Mouse Properties
control main.cpl keyboard - Keyboard Properties
control main.cpl pc card  - PC Card
control main.cpl power    - Power Management
```

On my Windows 11 laptop it now only handles the mouse and keyboard, though since these are the main way I interact with the laptop I guess the name "main" is still just about appropriate.